# too many values to unpack (expected 2) no Django

Tags: python, django

Estou com este trecho de código no Django, a intenção é inserir, se já existir o `ds_user_id` então ele atualiza o usuário com esse `ds_user_id` ao invés de criar um novo

```
ds_user_id = int(post_login['ds_user_id'])
csrftoken = post_login['csrftoken']
cookies = json.dumps(str(post_login['cookies']))

defaults = {
  'username': username,
  'password': password,
  'ds_user_id': ds_user_id,
  'csrftoken': csrftoken,
  'cookies': cookies,
  'status': 0
}

try:
  obj = User.objects.get(ds_user_id=ds_user_id)

  for key, value in defaults.keys():
    setattr(obj, key, value)
  obj.save()
except User.DoesNotExist:
  new_values = {
    'username': username,
    'password': password,
    'ds_user_id': ds_user_id,
    'csrftoken': csrftoken,
    'cookies': cookies,
    'status': 0
  }

  new_values.update(defaults)

  obj = User(**new_values)
  obj.save()
```

O `insert` funcionou porém, ao tentar logar novamente, recebo:

> too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Eu não estou entendendo muito bem, mas eu acho que é esta linha que está **buguizando** meu código:

```
for key, value in defaults.keys():
```

Comment: Sim, é exatamente essa linha que está "buguizando". Ao fazer `defaults.keys()` você obtém **apenas** as chaves do dicionário, não os valores. Se quer ambos deve utilizar `defaults.items()`.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, aproveitando o tópico, gostaria de melhorar a pergunta pra não receber negativos, estou quase sendo bloqueado :( mas não tenho mto tempo

Comment: Apergutna está ok. A resposta é simples e correta - a do Anderson - que deveria ter colocado como resposta.

Eu não entendo o que leva as pessoas a negativar algumas perguntas aqui - as vezes parece que pelo fato de não saberem responder, negativam.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você utilizou o método [`dict.keys`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys), que retorna um objeto iterável com **apenas** as chaves do dicionário e o erro ocorre por fazer a desconstrução de tupla de um valor em duas variáveis.

```
for key, value in defaults.keys():
    setattr(obj, key, value)
```

Como a sua intenção é obter o par chave/valor, utilize [`dict.items`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items):

```
for key, value in defaults.items():
    setattr(obj, key, value)
```

Comment: Ok, eu ia botar a culpa na documentação, mas eu fui la ver e lá esta items() asokoaskokaoskokas foi erro meu, porem através desse erro *tosco* vc explicou uma coisa importante pra mim, obrigado